# numpy, choice in loop between concatenating or initializing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have several arrays that I want to initialize.  I want to loop through each array so that the array holds no data, it gets initialized by some method, but if it does hold data, new data gets added to it via `numpy.stack`.  I tried this:

```
a = np.array(0)
b = np.array(0)
c = np.array(0)

while True:

    data_set_num = infile.readline()
    if not data_set_num: break

    for arr in (a, b, c):
        new_arr = get_new_array(infile)
        try:
            arr = np.stack((arr, new_arr))
        except:
            arr = np.array(new_arr)
```

But after execution of the loop, I don't have anything:

```
>>> a.shape
()
```

Same for `b` and `c`.  Clearly I did not understand how `arr` references the three arrays.  Anyone know how to do what I am trying to do?  I can, of course, unroll the inner loop, but that seems horribly "unpythonic".

Comment: Even if you correct your bug, repeated concatenation is an extremely inefficient way to work with arrays.

Comment: `arr` references the arrays one-by-one. Then it gets replaced by `np.stack((arr, new_arr))` or `np.array(new_arr)`, both of which return new arrays. The name `arr` gets bound to the new reference, not `a` or `b` or `c`.

Comment: @Mad Physicist  Yes, as I now understand.  Now my question is how do I do what I need to do?  Thanks.

Comment: You can try making a list of arrays instead of `a` `b` `c`, do `x = [np.array(0) for _ in range(3)]`, then loop over `for ind, arr in enumerate(x)`, and set `x[ind]` instead of `arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring the fact that concatenating arrays via stacking is a terrible way to go about doing it, you can need to fix the name binding issue in your code.

The problem is that `arr` references (gets bound to) the arrays one-by-one (as you would expect). Then it gets replaced by `np.stack((arr, new_arr))` or `np.array(new_arr)`, both of which return new arrays. The name `arr` gets bound to the new reference, not `a` or `b` or `c`.

A direct solution would be to make a list of arrays instead of using `a`, `b`, `c`. Do something like

```
x = [np.array(0) for _ in range(3)]

while True:

    data_set_num = infile.readline()
    if not data_set_num:
        break

    for ind, arr in enumerate(x):
        new_arr = get_new_array(infile)
        try:
            x[ind] = np.stack((arr, new_arr))
        except:
            x[ind] = np.array(new_arr)
```

There are a couple of major flaws here. For one thing, you should not be using `try...except` for something so simple. For another, if you must stack arrays together, try to do it all at once instead of doing incremental reallocations.

Also, your code appears to be looping over the same set of arrays over and over within the `while True:` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
arrays = []
while True:
    #data_set_num = infile.readline()
    #if not data_set_num: break
    arr = np.array(0)
    for count in range(3):
        #new_arr = get_new_array(infile)
        new_arr = np.array([[count+1,count+2],[count+3,count+4]])
        try:
            arrays.append(np.stack((arr, new_arr)))
        except:
            arrays.append(np.array(new_arr))
    break
print str(arrays[0])
print str(arrays[1])
print str(arrays[2])
```

Comment: `print` will automatically call `str`. The last three statements could be reduced to `for x in arrays: print x`.